# Green's Theorem - Trouble understanding problem

Tags: calculus

Find the area enclosed by the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ (Using green's Theorem)

[image]

I am confused why we didn't use double integral here although answer makes sense without using double integral but I really don't understand why .

Comment: Well, yeah, you could brute force it by figuring out the right bounds and doing a double integral, but then you wouldn't be attacking the problem with Green's theorem.

Comment: Green's theorem can be used to express the area of a region in terms of a line integral (the one on the left of your displayed equation). See the bottom of the page [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GreensTheorem.aspx) for the derivation. The calculation in your post is arguably easier than using a double integral to find the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have helped you see the connection to the (typical) formal statement of Green's Theorem---as relating a double integral over $D$ to a line integral around the bounding curve of $D$---if they would have written the double integral first and *then* converted that to the line integral they began with. But alas...

See (3) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html) or the explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_Calculation) for why your text started with the integral they did.